# Haskell List function errors

Tags: haskell

The function enumerate_con should return a list of the booleans inside the con constructor. for example: `enumerate_con(Not(And(Con False)(Con True)))` should return `[False, True]`

Likewise: `enumerate_con(And(Con False)(Con False))` should return [False, False].

Here is the code I have:

```
 enumerate_con :: Formula -> [Bool]
 enumerate_con (And q1 q2) = enumerate_con q2 ++ enumerate_con q2
 enumerate_con (Not (Con True)) = [True]
 enumerate_con (Not (Con False)) = [False]
 enumerate_con (Con b) = b
```

Here is how formula is defined:

```
 data Formula = And Formula Formula
              | Not Formula
              | Con Bool
              deriving Show
```

Please help me fix the function so it works as intended

Comment: This is an okay question. A good question would also include the observations you make that seem in conflict with "it works as intended". For future questions, you can keep this in mind (and not just on StackOverflow). The mnemonic I use to remember what parts there are to a good question is "I did X, expecting Y to happen, but Z happened instead.". (This question has the X and the Y, but not the Z.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Not (And (Con True) (Con True))` can occur, but your pattterns will only work if the `Not` has as parameter a `Con True` or a `Con False`. You however do not need to check the data constructor of the item wrapped in a `Not`. You can implement this with `Not b` as pattern.

Another problem is that for `Con b`, you return `b`. But the output type should be a *list* of `Bool`s, not a single `Bool`, you thus should wrap this in a singleton list:

```
enumerate_con :: Formula -> [Bool]
enumerate_con (And q1 q2) = enumerate_con q2 ++ enumerate_con q2
enumerate_con (Not b) = enumerate_con b
enumerate_con (Con b) = [b]
```

Comment: Can you clarify why enumerate_con(Not (Con True)) = [True]
 enumerate_con (Not (Con False)) = [False] won't work?

Comment: `Not` can take an arbitrary formula. You are ignoring cases like `Not (And ... ...)`.